matchTemplate() missing detections and giving false positives, what can I do?
I'm trying to use opencv to detect objects in a video game. I have grabbed the image as a png and trimmed it so that the background is transparent, and yet, it only detects it at threshold levels ~ 0.6.
Needle image:

Haystack image:

This was done using a threshold of 0.8. Notice the amount of false positives, as well as a true negative on the detection.
Here is the python code.
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


class Vision:

    # properties
    needle_img = None
    needle_w = 0
    needle_h = 0
    method = None

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, needle_img_path, method=cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED):
        # load the image we're trying to match
        self.needle_img = cv.imread(needle_img_path, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

        # Save the dimensions of the needle image
        self.needle_w = self.needle_img.shape[1]
        self.needle_h = self.needle_img.shape[0]

        # There are 6 methods to choose from:
        # TM_CCOEFF, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, TM_CCORR, TM_CCORR_NORMED, TM_SQDIFF, TM_SQDIFF_NORMED
        self.method = method

    def find(self, haystack_img, threshold=0.9, debug_mode=None):
        # run the OpenCV algorithm
        base = self.needle_img[:, :, 0:3]
        alpha = self.needle_img[:, :, 3]
        alpha = cv.merge([alpha, alpha, alpha])
        result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, base, self.method,mask=alpha)

        # Get the all the positions from the match result that exceed our threshold
        locations = np.where(result >= threshold)
        locations = list(zip(*locations[::-1]))
        #print(locations)

        # First we need to create the list of [x, y, w, h] rectangles
        rectangles = []
        for loc in locations:
            rect = [int(loc[0]), int(loc[1]), self.needle_w, self.needle_h]
            # Add every box to the list twice in order to retain single (non-overlapping) boxes
            rectangles.append(rect)
            rectangles.append(rect)
        # Apply group rectangles
        # "Relative difference between sides of the rectangles to merge them into a group."
        rectangles, weights = cv.groupRectangles(rectangles, groupThreshold=1, eps=0.5)
        #print(rectangles)

        points = []
        if len(rectangles):
            #print('Found needle.')

            line_color = (0, 255, 0)
            line_type = cv.LINE_4
            marker_color = (255, 0, 255)
            marker_type = cv.MARKER_CROSS

            # Loop over all the rectangles
            for (x, y, w, h) in rectangles:

                # Determine the center position
                center_x = x + int(w/2)
                center_y = y + int(h/2)
                # Save the points
                points.append((center_x, center_y))

                if debug_mode == 'rectangles':
                    # Determine the box position
                    top_left = (x, y)
                    bottom_right = (x + w, y + h)
                    # Draw the box
                    cv.rectangle(haystack_img, top_left, bottom_right, color=line_color,
                                lineType=line_type, thickness=2)
                elif debug_mode == 'points':
                    # Draw the center point
                    cv.drawMarker(haystack_img, (center_x, center_y),
                                color=marker_color, markerType=marker_type,
                                markerSize=40, thickness=2)

        if debug_mode:
            cv.imshow('Matches', haystack_img)
            #cv.waitKey()
            #cv.imwrite('result_click_point.jpg', haystack_img)

        return points

I'm also using wincap to capture my screen in real time, but I think the underlying issue is in the image detection. If I'm feeding the needle image as the exact pixel perfect image that I want it to detect, why can't it properly detect it at high thresholds?

Template matching does not work properly, most of the time. Why you did not do object detection via yolo or find objects via surf or sift techniques?

@BarzanHayati that's wrong. it works fine, if you know how to use it, and when to use it. for this problem here, it's fine to use. OP's code is just using it wrong.

Your template does not perfectly match the instance in the haystack. Left: your template. Right: piece of the haystack, where I erased the surroundings. Ignore edge pixels, look at the pixels inside the objects.

Now that we've established that there cannot be a perfect match on this data, I hope you'll understand that you need to give the program some tolerance.
Now to the false positives:
 
Those happen because you chose a terrible matching mode for this data, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED. On (nearly) perfectly flat areas, this goes completely wild due to division.
When the instances in the haystack are pixel-perfect copies of the needle, you should use TM_SQDIFF or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED. That also goes for when the instances have a little difference, but they generally have the same brightness and color.
This is the result of using TM_SQDIFF_NORMED, with a mask argument derived from the needle, and accepting a difference of 0.2. The instance has a difference of 0.192.


Thank you it works perfectly. I never understood the contextual applications of the different methods used template matching but you explained it well given the example.
